# save data into db from 2 dimensional array - php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 dimensional array to be save into mysql. The problem is, how do i get the data from that array and save it into DB Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[1a] => Array
    (
        [ans] => 1
    )

[2a] => Array
    (
        [ans] => 1
        [oth] => ABC
    )

[3a] => Array
    (
        [ans] => 1
    )

[3b] => Array
    (
        [ans] => 2
    )

[3f] => Array
    (
        [oth] => 
    )
```

)

so when saved, it will be look like this:

```
| qid | ans | oth |
===================
|  1a |  1  |     |
|  2a |  1  | ABC |
|  3a |  1  |     |
|  3b |  2  |     |
|  3f |     |     |
===================
```

please help me n thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information regarding your columns, whether or not the columns accept NULL values, if not what are their defaults? It'll make a big difference in the structure of any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have the array with name x

```
foreach($x as $key=>$details)
{
   $qid = $key;
   $ans = $details["ans"];
   $oth = $details["oth"];
   //Then Save to DB
   // Insert into table (qid,ans,oth) values('$qid',$ans,'$oth') ...

}
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the entries where those array keys don't exist. The OP will need to provide column details (NULL, DEFAULT) before you can handle them though.

Comment: I think the vars $oth and $ans will get the NULL value if there was no array key while looping , then the default value of the columns in the table will be inserted . thank you .

Comment: It wouldn't work that way sadly. If you don't use isset($array[<key] the script will though errors and if it did Sql wouldn't translate the ("1a",,) missing values into NULL.

Comment: I agree the second sentence ("1a",,) , but i think it won't throw php errors .

Comment: It'll depend on the version of Php; they've been strict about array keys since 5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($your_array as $qid => $value) {
   $ans = isset($value['ans']) ? $value['ans'] : null;
   $oth = isset($value['oth']) ? $value['oth'] : null;
   //then you get the $qid, $ans, $oth and insert them to the db.
   ....
}
```